# Show that $ \forall n \in \mathbb N$, $9\mid\left(10^n + 3\cdot4^{n+2} +5\right)$ using congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, divisibility

Using congruence theory, show that $ \forall n \in \mathbb N$, $9\mid\left(10^n + 3 \cdot 4^{n+2} +5\right)$. The proof is quite simple with induction, but how can it be proved with congruences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving divisibility by $9$ for $10^n + 3 \times 4^{n+2} + 5$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237927/proving-divisibility-by-9-for-10n-3-times-4n2-5)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Shouldn't it be the new question that is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Age does not necessarily decide which question should be a duplicate target - this was discussed several times on meta, for example, [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417) and several of [the linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16417). Other factors which I thought are relevant here: 1. This question is less general (it restricts the methods which can be used). 2. It seems quite probable that this question could be closed for lack of context - closing as a duplicate seems less harsh to me.

Comment: I guess that discussion about the direction of the closure could be longer - if needed, feel free to ping me [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2021/9/1). (So that we do not leave here too many comments.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

As $10\equiv1\pmod 9, 10^n \equiv1^n\equiv1$

$\displaystyle 4^{n+2}=(1+3)^{n+2}$
$\displaystyle=1+\binom{n+2}13+\binom{n+2}23^2+\cdots+3^{n+2}\equiv1+(n+2)3\pmod 9\equiv3n+7$

Can you take it from here?

---

Another way

$$10^n+3\cdot4^{n+2}+5=(10^n-1^n)+3\left(4^{n+2}-1^{n+2}\right)+1+3+5$$

Using congruence,

$\displaystyle4\equiv1\pmod 3\implies 4^{n+2}\equiv1^{n+2}\pmod3\equiv1$

and $10^n\equiv1\pmod9$

Comment: Good afternoon, Lab Bhattacharjee. Your first aproach gives us $10^n + 3.4^{n+2} +5 \equiv 1 +9n + 21 + 5 (mod 9) \equiv 9(n+3) \equiv 0 (mod 9)$. But in you second aproach, you got $(mod 3)$ and $(mod 9)$ mixed. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Walterr, good observation. Have you noticed $3$ as the multiplier for the second term?

Comment: $1o^n +3.4^{n+2} +5 \equiv 1\pmod 9 +3 \pmod 3 + 5\pmod 9$. How to conclude?

Comment: @Walterr, we can write $10^n=1+9a,4^{n+2}=1+3b$  So, $$10^n+3\cdot4^{n+2}+5=1+9a+3(1+3b)+5=\cdots$$ Is it ok?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$10^{n+1}+3\cdot4^{n+1+2}+5=10\cdot10^{n}+3\cdot4\cdot4^{n+2}+5=$$
$$=(1+9)\cdot10^{n}+12\cdot4^{n+2}+5=(1+9)\cdot10^{n}+(3+9)\cdot4^{n+2}+5=$$
$$=(10^{n}+3\cdot4^{n+2}+5)+9(10^{n}+4^{n+2})$$